# Can AND/OR use a recursive function to get the value and use it in Common Lisp?

Tags: function, recursion, common-lisp

I have been stuck on this for a while. i have tried and I am not getting it. I thought I was getting it, but the fact that this isn't working is confusing. I should due getting 1 but keep getting nil. The purpose is to simplify the expression using the rules(which I added below). My problem:

```
(defun simplify (main-list)
  (setq count 1)

  (if (and (eq t (atom (car (cdr main-list))))
           (eq t (atom (car (cdr (cdr main-list))))))
      (print "this says that the 2 ands are cons cells"))

  (if (and (eq nil (cdr main-list))
           (eq t (atom (car main-list))))
      (print "reached end of file, going back now"))

  (if (eq 'and (car main-list))
      (progn
        (if (and (eq t (atom (car (cdr main-list))))
                 (eq nil (atom (car (cdr (cdr main-list))))))
            (if (or (eq nil (car (cdr main-list)))
                    (simplify (car (cdr (cdr main-list)))))
                nil
                (if (eq 1 (car (cdr main-list)))
                    (simplify (car (cdr (cdr main-list))))
                    (if (eq 1 (simplify (car (cdr (cdr main-list)))))))))

        (if (and (eq t (atom (car (cdr main-list))))
                 (eq t (atom (car (cdr (cdr main-list))))))
            (if (or (eq nil (car (cdr main-list)))
                    (eq nil (car (cdr (cdr main-list)))))
                nil
                (if (eq 1 (car (cdr main-list)))
                    (car (cdr (cdr main-list)))
                    (if (eq 1 (car (cdr (cdr main-list))))
                        (car (cdr main-list)))))))))
```

The list I am using is:

```
(and 1 (and 1 1))
```

This is a simple version of what I am trying to accomplish, but I am tackling it a step at a time since I am completely new to the language. These are the rules for the AND I am suppose to follow for this Homework:

```
(and x nil) => nil; 
(and nil x) => nil;
(and x 1) => x; 
(and 1 x) => x;
```

I have tested it by doing

```
(simplify (car(cdr(cdr x))))
```

and I added counts to see if its even looping, but it is not. So my guess it has something to do with the recursive function calls that are within the if statements in the first block of code. Any explanations as to why would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you format the code to Lisp standards, please?

Comment: I tried, but honestly, the point isn't to learn the indentations first before the actual language... Thats what it sounds like you are implying.

Comment: your code is unreadable without proper indenting.

Comment: Indentations are just as much a part of common lisp code as they are in python code IMO. With a good editor, the indentations replace the need to think about all of those parentheses. I second that the code is not readable as is.

Comment: setq does not introduce local variables. LET does. (eq t (atom foo)) is just (atom foo). (eq nil (atom foo)) is just (not (atom foo)). EQ does not work with numbers. USe EQL or =. Use functions like FIRST, SECOND, THIRD instead of repeated CAR CDR CDR CDR CDR...

Comment: the first print says something different than the code does.

Comment: the second print talks about a file. but there is no file at all.

Comment: you should document your code in plain english, so we get an idea what want to accomplish. Also use varables instead of multiple times repeating the same code.

Comment: The last time I had comments explaining things in my code someone complained that it was there. I apologize. Its really hard to gauge what everyone wants, and my code is hard to read. My professor said it would happen as we are learning the language. I will edit it with what I have now, as I decided to scrap it and go a different route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(defun simplify (expression)
  (if (consp expression)
      (destructuring-bind (op arg1 arg2)
          expression
        (ecase op
          (and (cond ((or (null arg1) (null arg2))
                      nil)
                     ((eql 1 arg1)
                      (simplify arg2))
                     ((eql 1 arg2)
                      (simplify arg1))))))
    expression))
```